# How create JPA/persistence for a SQL view

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, view, persistence, identity

I'm actually trying to create the persistence of a MySql database in a Spring Boot project with IntelliJ.

It wasn't a problem with classic table but I have an error message for the "view" table:

**No identifier specified for entity:**

Here is a view example:

```
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_view", schema = "db", catalog = "")
public class EmployeeView {
    private int ageId;
    private String ageLabel;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "age_id")
    public int getAgeId() {
        return ageId;
    }

    public void setAgeId(int ageId) {
        this.ageId = ageId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "age_label")
    public String getAgeLabel() {
        return ageLabel;
    }

    public void setAgeLabel(String ageLabel) {
        this.ageLabel = ageLabel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        EmployeeView employeeView = (EmployeeView) o;
        return ageId == employeeView.ageId && Objects.equals(ageLabel, employeeView.ageLabel);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(ageId, ageLabel);
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no ID column because this view doesn't have identifier. Maybe it's a simple problem because that's the first time I create persistence for views. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

So, just in case someone take a look to this question, I post my answer:

I've just added a fake ID like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "iD", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long iD;
```

Then, just to be sure, because it's a view and not a table (I don't have to upadate it), I've added the annotation @Immutable like this:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "view_object", schema = "BDD", catalog = "")
public class ViewObject {}
```

I don't have anymore the error message and I can build the application. I don't know if it's a good practice and if an expert want to give me a correction, it'll be with pleasure!